# Appcenter android build fails to install in device

Tags: android, react-native, ndk-build, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I have configured my react-native app in appcenter for build and distribution. Everything was working fine and all of a sudden, build failed with the following error

```
> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols FAILED
Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.

> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Followed this link https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2144 and updated my grade file to

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
   }
```

and gradle-wrapper.properties to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

after this the build worked but the app distributed after the build failed to installed on devices with "App Not Installed" error. I tried different versions and no success so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the following settings

in graddle-wrapper.properties updated the distributionUrl to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip
```

in android/build.gradle updated gradle version to

```
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
```

Updated react-native version to 0.65.1

```
npm i react-native@0.65.1
```

updated all related packages to be compatible with this react-native version

```
npm update "react-native"
```

after this, I was able to build it in appcenter and was able to distribute and install the app

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. After checking which ndk versions are supported in VSAC via looking at build logs I updated `android/build.gradle` with following ndk version & it worked.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
        ndkVersion = "18.1.5063045"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried with this. Build was successful in appcenter but the distributed app didnt install on the phone. It again gave 'App Not Installed' error

Comment: Have you reverted the changes you made to the gradle versions in both `android/build.gradle` and `gradle-wrapper.properties` ?

Comment: I reverted to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip and classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3") and the build failed now

Comment: Can you please share your versions? I can try with that

Comment: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip` in `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

`classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3")` in `build.gradle`.

What does the build logs state ?

Comment: I was getting this error in build log, same as the error posted in the question

Comment: ```> Task :app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols FAILED
Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.

> Task :app:mergeExtDexRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:stripReleaseDebugSymbols'.
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: arm-linux-androideabi

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```